# Define Matlab Class with Attributes of Another Class

Tags: matlab, class, oop

I'm trying to construct a class framework for a neural network (ANN) in Matlab by defining a Node class:

```
function NodeObject = Node(Input, Weights, Activation)

Features.Input      = [];
Features.Weights    = [];
Features.Activation = [];

Features.Input      = Input;
Features.Weights    = Weights;
Features.Activation = Activation;

NodeObject = class(Features, 'Node');
```

Where here the input is an integer (expected number of inputs), Weights is a vector of length `Features.Input`, and `Features.Activation` is a string that references an activation function stored in the methods.

What I want to do next is construct a cell array of nodes and define a Network class based on this array:

```
function Architecture = Network(NodeArray) 

ANN.Layers      = []; % Number of layers in architecture
ANN.LayerWidths = []; % Vector of length ANN.Layers containing width of each layer
ANN.NodeArray   = []; % Original input is cell array with layers in ascending order (input at top, output at bottom) with nodes in each row.
ANN.InputSizes  = [];

% Find number of layers
ANN.Layers = length(NodeArray(:,1));

% Find width of each layer
Widths = zeros(ANN.Layers,1);
for i = 1:length(Widths)
    Widths(i) = length(NodeArray(:,i));
end
ANN.LayerWidths = Widths;

% Pass NodeArray to Network class
ANN.NodeArray = NodeArray;

% Construct cell of input sizes
InputSizes = [];
for i = 1:ANN.Layers
    for j = 1:Widths(i)
        InputSizes(i,j) = NodeArray{i,j}.Inputs;
    end
end

ANN.InputSizes = InputSizes;



Architecture = class(ANN, 'Network');
```

The attribute `ANN.InputSizes` tries to extract the attributes from a `Node` object, but my code doesn't allow me to do this.  How do I amend this problem, or do you recommend a different architecture to this problem all together?  Currently my classes `Node` and `Network` are contained in two separate directories, but I have a feeling that there is something else I'm not seeing.  For reference, I have absolutely no prior experience in OOP, and from what I've gathered it seems Matlab is not the best environment in which to implement these structures.  At the moment though I don't have enough experience to implement this type of framework in another language.

Comment: It may be easier to use the `classdef` format for defining your classes.

Comment: @Suever I did try defining a `Node2` class with the `classdef` format saved in the `@Network` directory, but the `Network` definition didn't recognize it.  Part of this problem is in how I'm defining my classes, but part of it too might be how I'm linking my directories.

Comment: The @Folder has to have the same name as the class, so it would need to be `@Node2`. But with `classdef` definitions, you don't need the `@Folder` at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `InputSizes` isn't a cell. You initialize it to a `double` array (`[]`) and then fill it as such. If you want to define it as a cell you should do something like

```
InputSizes = cell();
for i = 1:ANN.Layers
    for j = 1:Widths(i)
        InputSizes{i,j} = NodeArray{i,j}.Inputs;
    end
end
```

All of that, you should really look into defining your classes using  a `classdef` file, as it is much more straightforward.

**`Node.m`**

```
classdef Node < handle

    properties
        Inputs
        Weights
        Activation
    end

    methods
        function obj = Node(inputs, weights, activation)
            obj.Inputs = inputs;
            obj.Weights = weights;
            obj.Activation = activation;
        end
    end
end
```

**`Network.m`**

```
classdef Network < handle
    properties
        NodeArray
    end

    properties (Dependent)
        Layers
        LayerWidths
        InputSizes          
    end

    methods
        function obj = Network(nodes)
            obj.NodeArray = nodes;
        end

        function result = get.Layers(obj)
            result = size(obj.NodeArray, 1);
        end

        function result = get.LayerWidths(obj)
            result = size(obj.NodeArray, 2);
        end

        function result = get.InputSizes(obj)
            result = arrayfun(@(x)x.Inputs, obj.NodeArray, 'uniformoutput', 0);
        end
    end
end
```

As far as suggesting a better layout, that's subject to the opinion of the individual developer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I'm trying to implement this right now, but Matlab isn't recognizing the function handle for `get.InputSizes`.  Specifically, in `arrayfun(@(x).Inputs, ...` it gives me an error with respect to calling the inputs.  Do you have a recommendation?

Comment: It sees the `.` in `@(x).Inputs` as an error.  Specifically it gives me "unexpected MATLAB operator."

Comment: @Mnifldz Oh sorry about that. It was a typo. Fixed now.

Comment: After I come up with a node array on the command line, I implement the code above and define a `Network` object with this array, but it doesn't seem to extract the input sizes from the nodes.  That field remains empty in the object.  Matlab also gives me back an error if I try to call the function `get.InputSizes`, so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: How are you calling it? It works fine for me like: `n(1) = Node(1,2,3); n(2) = Node(4,5,6); net = Network(n); net.InputSizes`

Comment: I actually found another way of implementing it with only one class definition.  I'm upvoting your answer, thanks for your help.

Comment: @Mnifldz Technically this answer answers your question I believe so even though you ultimately went with another solution (there are many possible solutions), it's appreciated to accept a solution if it worked for you.